# ng service-worker does not cache data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

ng service-worker caches data only for the time specified in the Cache-Control response header: public, max-age = 60, s-maxage = 60. After 60 seconds in offline mode, the response 504 Gateway Timeout (from ServiceWorker) comes to the request.

```
  {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
      "index": "/index.html",
      "assetGroups": [
        {
          "name": "app",
          "installMode": "prefetch",
          "resources": {
            "files": [
              "/favicon.ico",
              "/index.html",
              "/manifest.webmanifest",
              "/*.css",
              "/*.js"
            ]
          }
        },
         {
          "name": "assets",
          "installMode": "lazy",
          "updateMode": "prefetch",
          "resources": {
            "files": [
              "/assets/**",
              "/app/app.component.ts",
              "/*.(pdf|odt|eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "dataGroups": [
      {
              "name": "github-api",
          "urls": ["**//api.github.com/**"],
          "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "performance",
            "maxSize": "100",
            "maxAge": "7d"

        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you config your service worker ? Which command you run to install service worker to your angular app ?

Comment: With this command:
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*